# I have 3 scripts one duplicate a script and the third should get created objects but I can't get this objects. How can I get the objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 scripts one duplicate a script and the third should get created objects but I can't get this objects. How can I get the objects?

The first script is Generate Stairs Units. This script is attached to a empty GameObject.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateStairsUnits : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Stairs Units Prefab")]
    public GameObject stairsUnitsPrefab;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Settings")]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int numberOfUnits = 1;
    public static GameObject Unit;

    private int oldNumberOfUnits = 0;
    private List<GameObject> units = new List<GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        oldNumberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;

        var unitsParent = GameObject.Find("Stairs Units");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
        {
            Unit = Instantiate(stairsUnitsPrefab, unitsParent.transform);
            Unit.name = "Stairs " + i.ToString();
            units.Add(Unit);
            Unit.AddComponent<MoveObjects>();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }
}
```

The GenerateStairsUnits script duplicate a prefab of the second script Generate Stairs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateStairs : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Stairs Prefb")]
    public GameObject stairsPrefab;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Platforms")]
    public bool addPlatforms = false;
    public GameObject platformsPrefab;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Settings")]
    public float delay = 3;
    public int stairsNumber = 5;
    public Vector3 stairsStartPosition;
    public Vector3 stairSize;
    public Vector3 stairsSize;
    public float stepWidthFactor = 1f;
    public GameObject moveobjects;

    private Vector3 stairsPosition;
    private GameObject stairsParent;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        moveobjects = GameObject.Find("Move Objects");

        stairsParent = new GameObject();
        stairsParent.name = "Stairs";
        stairsParent.transform.parent = GenerateStairsUnits.Unit.transform;
        StartCoroutine(BuildStairs());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private IEnumerator BuildStairs()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= stairsNumber; i++)
        {

            stairsPosition = new Vector3(
                    stairsStartPosition.x,
                    stairsStartPosition.y + (i * stairsSize.y),
                    stairsStartPosition.z + (i * stairsSize.y) * stepWidthFactor);

            GameObject stair = Instantiate(
                    stairsPrefab,
                    stairsPosition,
                    Quaternion.identity);

            stair.tag = "Stair";
            stair.transform.parent = transform;
            stair.transform.localScale = stairSize;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

The GenerateStairsUnits also add as component the third script Move Objects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> objectsToMove = new List<GameObject>();
    public AnimationCurve curve;
    public float stepsPerSecond = 1f;
    public bool changeDirection = false;

    private Vector3 trackStart;
    private Vector3 trackEnd;
    private Vector3 horizontalTravel;
    private float verticalTravel;
    private float divisor;
    private float phase = 0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    public void Init()
    {
        if (curve == null)
        {
            curve = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(0, 0), new Keyframe(1, 1));
        }
        curve.preWrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp;
        curve.postWrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp;

        trackStart = objectsToMove[0].transform.position;
        int count = objectsToMove.Count;
        var span = objectsToMove[count - 1].transform.position - trackStart;

        divisor = 1f / count;
        horizontalTravel = (count + 1) * span * divisor;
        horizontalTravel.y = 0f;

        verticalTravel = span.y;
        trackEnd = trackStart + (count + 1) * span / count;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (objectsToMove != null && objectsToMove.Count > 0 && curve != null)
        {
            AnimationCurve();
        }
    }

    private void AnimationCurve()
    {
        phase = Mathf.Repeat(phase + stepsPerSecond * divisor * Time.deltaTime, 1f);

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
        {
            float t = Mathf.Repeat(phase + i * divisor, 1f);
            // Get the height of the curve at this step.
            float curveHeight = curve.Evaluate(t) * verticalTravel;

            if (changeDirection)
            {
                objectsToMove[i].transform.position = trackStart                // First step
                                  - horizontalTravel * t      // evenly spaced horizontal
                                  + curveHeight * Vector3.up; // curving vertical
            }
            else
            {
                objectsToMove[i].transform.position = trackStart                // First step
                                  + horizontalTravel * t      // evenly spaced horizontal
                                  + curveHeight * Vector3.up; // curving vertical
            }
        }
    }

    private void StraightLineTrack()
    {
        float divisor = 1f / objectsToMove.Count;

        // Compute the current phase of the escalator, 
        // from 0 (1st step at track start) to 1 (1st step at track end)
        phase = Mathf.Repeat(phase + stepsPerSecond * divisor * Time.deltaTime, 1f);

        // Place each step a proportional distance along the track.
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
        {
            float t = Mathf.Repeat(phase + i * divisor, 1f);
            objectsToMove[i].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(trackStart, trackEnd, t);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem:

After duplicating the GenerateStairs and creating stairs for each Stairs Unit and adding the Move Objects component the result is:

In the Hierarchy I have empty GameObject name Stairs Units. Under Stairs Units there are the Units Stairs 0, Stairs 1, Stairs 2, Stairs 3, Stairs 4. And under each Stairs there are the Stairs.

Each Unit for example Stair 0 have also attached the Move Objects script.

Now my problem is how to get the stairs of each unit to the Move Objects objectsToMove List.

In the Move Objects I have a List name objectsToMove. For example under Stairs 0 there are 10 stairs I need to get this 10 stairs to the objectsToMove of Stairs 0. Then the next 10 stairs of the Stairs 1 and so on. But I can't figure out how to add the stairs of each unit to the objectsToMove.

[image: Stairs]

In the end the objectsToMove that what should move the stairs of each Stairs Unit.

Comment: You can't insert them manually? by pressing the side arrow and drag&drop them into the items of the list?

Comment: `Unit = Instantiate(stairsUnitsPrefab, unitsParent.transform);` why you create the static variable in a loop, it can only exist one copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Stairs N` gameobject attaches two scripts `GenerateStairs` and `MoveObjects` on it, you can get the `MoveObjects`'s reference by calling `GetComponent` before generating the `Stair`s and pass it to the `BuildStairs` function.

```
void Start()
{
    ...
    MoveObjects moveObjects = gameObject.GetComponent<MoveObjects>();
    StartCoroutine(BuildStairs(moveObjects));
}
```

By getting the `MoveObjects`'s reference, you can then pass this reference into your `BuildStairs` function and add those generating `stair`s into list `objectsToMove` inside `MoveObjects`.

Modify the function and pass `MoveObjects` like below:

```
private IEnumerator BuildStairs(MoveObjects moveObjects)
{
    ...
    moveObjects.objectsToMove.add (stair);
    ...
}
```

About [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html).